# If I create an "Access Point" server, could I have unlimited data on my phone?

Tags: internet, mobile

The access point I am talking about is for phones; as in the method for connecting to data services. In the Access Point Names setting on my AT&T phone, I see these settings:

- Name: ATT Nextgenphone
- APN: nxtgenphone
- MMSC: http://mmsc.mobile.att.net
- Multimedia message proxy: proxy.mobile.att.net
- Multimedia message port: 80

The rest of the settings I don't believe I should give out. But, if I created my own server to do this on my own Internet connection, and changed my phone's settings to use that server, would it be possible for me to use that connection anywhere and therefore, have unlimited data?

If so, how can I create one?

Comment: Access points are only for WiFi access.  It does not relate to the data limits you might have for 4G LTE.

Comment: I said not that kind of access point. The access point I am talking about is for phones; as in the method for connecting to data services.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about servers and protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.There are several parameters when your mobile connection is validated at the Operator's Network and APN is one among them.This is the explanation from a layman point of view.

As per the GSM,3G,LTE standards the procedure of enabling data services for a subscriber is known as Attach.In this procedure UE/Mobile will have to send its parameters like TMSI,APN and another couple of parameters to authenticate the itself on the network. Depending upon the technology you use the service will be authenticated from the network by BSC(2G)(base station controller along with SGSN or from EPC side(LTE))

Even if you manage to create a new configuration at your phone and tried to attach the phone with network,The request will not get authenticated and data service will not be activated.

Just for you to understand,the operator network equipment vendors are normally Nokia,Ericsson,Alcatel lucent and Zte.Almost all the security aspects will be covered at multiple stages of the product deployment.On the other side,3gpp standards are very well defined to make sure unauthorized access are NACKed from the network as well.